# move tabs underneath snackbar when it pops up and move them back when it is gone in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, tabs, snackbar

I wanted to know if there is a way to readjust tabs underneath a snackbar when it pops up at the top of the page? Like let's say tabs are at the very top of the page, snackbar with a height of 10px pops up at the top of the page then I want the snackbar to be the top element and the tabs to move underneath it when it is shown without them overlapping on each other?

Comment: What are you trying to do with the snackbar? eg. When the user presses button "A", I want to let the user know that process "b" has started.   Generally speaking a snackbar should be at the bottom of a page, and you shouldn't animate other components when the snackbar moves into view.

Comment: I understand that the snackbar is at the bottom of the page but for this specific task the snackbar should be at the top of the page. That being said, in this task I want to listen to specific event, if true I want the snackbar to pop up and move the tabs underneath them. I got the event part ready just need to know how to move the tabs underneath the snackbar

Answer (score 0):

Here's a stackblitz that might do what you want

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f9k7ev

Basically what I'm doing is triggering some code (button, event, whatever) to set my snackbar to open up top, and adding a class to our container (here, a div, for you, your tabs) to move them down by an arbitrary value (here we do 10em) using CSS.  We also listen to our afterDismissed() subscription to come back and then remove that class.

```
 constructor(private _snackBar: MatSnackBar) {}

 openSnackBar() {
      const ourSnackbar = this._snackBar.openFromComponent(PizzaPartyComponent, {
           duration: this.durationInSeconds * 1000,
           verticalPosition: 'top'
      });

      ourSnackbar.afterDismissed().subscribe(() => this.removeOurClass());

      let elements = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
      Array.from(elements).forEach(element => {
           element.classList.add('moved');
      });
 }

 removeOurClass() {
      let elements = document.getElementsByTagName("div");

      Array.from(elements).forEach(element => {
           element.classList.remove('moved');
      });
 }
```

and our CSS

```
.moved {
    margin-top: 10em;
}
```

and the HTML we're moving (not the snackbar), the div we look for.

```
<div class="mat-app-background basic-container">
    <snack-bar-component-example>loading</snack-bar-component-example>
</div>
```